# Affinity Designer: Change What Node of Shape Snaps to Grid

Tags: affinity-designer

I am using affinity designer to do some precisely positioned icon design.  I have a 1pt grid in place and am having things snap to it, which works well.

However, sometimes I have a shape that I'm dragging around that is not regularly shaped (not all points align to the grid).  I would like to have a particular node snap to the grid while the others maintain their shape relative to this node.

For example, let's say I have a shape that is 3.5pt tall.  I may want to align the bottom-left node to the grid, but the snapping will only use the top node.

Is there a way to pick which node is snapping to the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Select the shape in the layers list or with the normal selection tool. Take the node tool. Select with it all nodes of the selected shape. Drag one of the nodes. It will snap and others will follow. Prevent other snapping options if you want easy snap to grid.